# firebase update add new entry every time when fetching data using once

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I wants to update the my child node data using below code snippet

```
let codeBankRef = firebase.database().ref().child("code")
codeBankRef.once('value', s => {
  console.log(s.val())
  if (s.exists()) {
    console.log('snap exists', s.val())
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      codes: Object.keys(s.val()).map(k => ({ ...s.val()[k], firebaseUrl: k }))
    })
    return
  }
  else {
    this.setState({
      loading: false
    })
  }
})
```

When updating a child of node and fetching using `once` there is a new entry  in the list. `snapshot.ref.update({})` updates the child node but fetch an extra entry when using `once` function to fetch the value

Comment: When using "on" to fetch value it is coming correctly. So what is the difference in using "on" in place of "once" when updating data

Comment: Can u add your code with `update` method....?